# How to show video in WPF from SDK that needs a handle (intptr)

Tags: c#, wpf, video, handle

I need to show a video that is obtained using a DVR SDK, which needs a handle (intptr) of a control where to put the video. My problem is that now we are using WPF and I can't find a way to show the video on any wpf control because they don't have a handle. I know that I can use a windowsformhost and put a panel (or any other System.Windows.Forms.Control) inside and send its handle to the SDK, but if I do that I will have the AeroSpace problem (the windowsformhost is always on top of every other wpf element) and I have some stuff that I need to show over the video.

The SDK function is something like this:

```
GetVideo(IntPtr ControlHandle);
```

Can I get the video from the memory pointed by the IntPtr? or is there any wpf component or project that can be used to show the video?

Answer (score 0):

You only have three choices:

1. Use a WindowsFormsHost
2. Pass the WPF Window's handle which means the video would use the entire window (assuming that it didn't contend with DirectX for drawing rights to the window).
3. Get a different API, preferably one that uses DirectX

Comment: We end up using a WindowsFormsHost even tho its not what we wanted but it works for now.